# Svelte dynamic style handling

Tags: javascript, styles, svelte

https://svelte.dev/repl/83031a6a492c4a30a861e4310209e9b6?version=3.24.0

Is there another approach instead of writing style direct into the raw style tag?:

```js
<div style="width: {width}; height: {height};">ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ</div>
```

Or; what is best practice in such cases, where the delivered style could be anything / is dynamic, and not preclassable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example:

```
<script>
  let bgcol="blue"
  let style=`color:red;background-color:${bgcol}`
</script>  
    ​
<h1 {style}> Hello <h1>
```

EDIT: `{style}` is shorthand for `style={style}`

You can find working example from REPL:

https://svelte.dev/repl/f039834923014cd7aca30c54d957c844?version=3.24.0